# Expresso Store EE 3.0 Support?

Tags: expresso-store

New to Expresso Store, but purchase this for a client who wants to build a pretty complicated store. I'm ready for the challenge, but realized that Expresso isn't compatible with 3.0 yet? Is this something that's in the works, or a hack that I can possibly use. Thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this neat website called 'google' to search for an answer and it yielded this result:

http://www.devdemon.com/blog/expressionengine-3.0-porting

Spoiler: It looks like Store is being ported.

Comment: Sarcasm.  Tsk! ;) Following their twitter feed is also useful for the latest https://twitter.com/devdemon

Comment: Lol, he'll never come back and accept, they never do,.

Comment: Guess that was a stupid question, even though I googled it before (and what a neat site...). I've never dealt with such a large 'upgrade' with EE before, so I apologize for the noob question. Thanks-

Comment: Thanks @stuartmcd69 although posting a link would do. And I accepted, just for you.

Comment: except that it is November and still nothing has progressed :P

Comment: Ditch it and use cartthrob instead. Time is $$